# Converting a data frame into named object in R

Tags: r, data-structures

Suppose I have the following data:

```
1415967_at 56258
1415968_a_at 20249
1415963_at 20249
1415966_a_at 16483
```

How can I obtain the following data structure:

```
$`1415967_at` 
[1]56258

$`1415968_a_at` 
[1]20249

$`1415963_at` 
[1]20249

$`1415966_a_at` 
[1]16483
```

I'm stuck with the following code:

```
 dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1484733/plain/")
  #...???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `as.list`:

```
setNames(as.list(dat[[2]]), dat[[1]])

# $`1415967_at`
# [1] 56258
# 
# $`1415968_a_at`
# [1] 20249
# 
# $`1415963_at`
# [1] 20249
# 
# $`1415966_a_at`
# [1] 16483
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Truly life saving. If you don't mind I have a following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238573/removing-redundant-entry-in-named-object-in-r)