# Removing redundant entry in named-object in R

Tags: r

With this data set,

```
1415967_at 56258
1415968_a_at 20249
1415963_at 20249
1415966_a_at 16483
```

I can managed to [convert to a named-list:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238175/converting-a-data-frame-into-named-object-in-r)

```
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1484733/plain/")
nl <- setNames(as.list(dat[[2]]), dat[[1]])
```

Later with this particular named-object 
we would like to remove redundant named entry (with `_at`),
where the numeric value is redundant. 
We will keep only the first occurrence.

Resulting in this new non redundant named-object:

```
$`1415967_at`
[1] 56258

$`1415968_a_at`
[1] 20249

$`1415966_a_at`
[1] 16483
```

In the above example  `1415968_a_at` and `1415963_at` is redundant
because the numeric value is the same:`20249`. 
Thus we keep only the first one `1415968_a_at`.
In reality the number of duplicate can varied (more than 2).

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude duplicates with:

```
n1[!duplicated(n1)]

# $`1415967_at`
# [1] 56258
# 
# $`1415968_a_at`
# [1] 20249
# 
# $`1415966_a_at`
# [1] 16483
```

Answer (score 1):

Or how about with `plyr` where you can add more complicate functions about which one to keep:

```
require(plyr)
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1484733/plain/")
dat <-ddply(dat,.(V2),summarize,V1=V1[1])
nl <- setNames(as.list(dat[[2]]), dat[[1]])
```

e.g. in the `ddply()` function you could replace:

```
  V1=V1[1]                   # PICK THE FIRST
```

with more complicated code on how to select